# When I have a form with multiple data blocks, which block saves first?

Tags: triggers, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm using Oracle forms builder 10g with oracle database version 11g R1.

I have a form with two data blocks in question: tableA and TableB, and a third table not on this form: TableC. Each of the corresponding tables has a database (not form) trigger associated with it. The database trigger for TableB updates part of TableA. The database trigger for TableA also updates tableC with data from TableA

My problem is that some of the data isn't coming into tableC properly now. I'm not sure how to handle this situation. I'm not entirely certain when the record for tableC is being created, or when the data from TableB is getting inserted into tableA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks are updated from a first to last order - ie, under the data blocks, if block A is listed first, then block B, the insert/update to table corresponding to block A fires first, then block B.

It's hard to say where the problem is without knowing what triggers are on, or what the triggers are doing. You could also ensure you've issued a commit to save the session data

Comment: Thanks Sathya! I wound up going with the tried and true "guess and check" method to piece it all together. Appreciate the answer!